# Help understanding forces in non-conservative systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, drag, dissipation, conservative-field

This might seem like a very simple problem, but it's stumping a few of us (myself obviously included).

We have been tasked with showing the mechanical energy of a particle is dissipated under the influence
of a drag force, the force is defined as being made up of a conservative and a drag component.

$$F(x)=-U'(x)-k|\dot{x}|^{n}\dot{x}\textrm{, where $k$ is the drag coefficient, and }k,n\gt0$$

Using the equation for mechanical energy, and after making some manipulations and a substitution I end up with the following.

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\dot{x}(m\ddot{x}-F(x)-k|\dot{x}|^{n}\dot{x})$$

My understanding is that $F(x)$ represents the conservative portion of the force (i.e.: $F(x)=m\ddot{x}$).

This is my question, am I correct in substituting $m\ddot{x}$ for $F(x)$ in the above equation, leaving me with $\frac{dE}{dt}=\dot{x}(-k|\dot{x}|^{n}\dot{x})\leq0$? Thus proving what I was asked to show.

Comment: Assuming your other manipulations are correct, then yes, you should substitute $F = m\ddot x$, since the trajectory $x$ is assumed to obey the equations of motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your statement "that $F(x)$ is the conservative portion of the force" is incorrect.  $F(x)$ is the *total force* on the mass and thus it must equal $ma$.  That's Newton's second law, the sum of the forces on an object is equal to its mass x acceleration.  And, yes, you're done (just take out that sentence and put in Newton's second law).